# windows bluetooth cannot get LE device

Tags: windows, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm trying to use IOCTL_BTH_GET_DEVICE_INFO to get bluetooth device list. But only got the ordinary bluetooth devices, the LE device never got listed. Should I use another way to obtain them ? Many thanks!!!

Comment: This is Bluetooth Classic API. You must use other way to work with BLE devices.

Comment: @MikePetrichenko Can you be more specific on what API should be used? Thanks.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/bluetooth-dev-faq